# Как обновить submodule до локальной версии?

Tags: git, git-submodule

Есть структура проекта:

1. Application - базовый репозиторий без submodule
2. Infrastructure - ссылается на Application(submodule)

Могу ли я обновить локально Application(без пуша в удаленную репу) и подтянуть эти изменения в Infrastructure? Правильно ли я понимаю, что submodule не подходит для частых обновлений(несколько раз/десять раз в день)?

P.S Все обычные репозитория и субмодули находятся в одной общей папке и к ним имею полный доступ. Просто хочу разделить большое решение на несколько поменьше.